# Queue type in D?

Tags: queue, message-queue, d

Many languages have a queue type (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html); I am unable to even find a library that implements a queue type (first in, first out data structure).  The lack of a queue surprises me.  Is there a different way that D does a queue?

The syntax I would expect would be similar to this:

```
//To create
Queue!string queue = new Queue!string;

//To add
queue.add("value");

//To access
string value = queue.get; //will remove from queue
//or
foreach (string value; queue) {}
```

How would this be done in D?  Or will I need to implement it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The containers that are currently in D's standard library are in std.container. They're a bit sparse though. A redesign of them is underway, but it has been for a while now, and who knows when that will be done. So, unfortunately, D's standard library is a bit weak in the area of containers. That being said, you could use [`std.container.dlist.DList`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_container_dlist.html) for a queue. It's a doubly linked list, which is usually how queue's are implemented internally, even if that's not the API that they expose.

Alternatively, http://code.dlang.org has several packages with containers.

But I'd suggest starting with `DList` and see how well it works for what you need. It should work just fine if you're looking for a basic queue. Just use `insertBack` to put things on the end, `front` to get at the first element, and `removeFront` to remove items from the front. And if you want an API that forces a queue, you can just wrap a `DList` in your own type.

Comment: You can also do it quite trivially with a simple array. You can even do it efficiently with an array and a couple helper methods; less than 20 lines of code.

Comment: This was what I needed.  I could not find a library before but I guess I wasn't sure what the library might be called.  @AdamD.Ruppe Yes that was what I though I might have to do but I was sure there would be a better way with fewer memory reallocations.  I never actually knew how queues at the low level were implemented.  Doubly linked lists! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)

Comment: The way I'd do it is a circular array (which might even be static size). Like `ubyte start, end; T[256] queue; void add_to_queue(T t) { queue[end++] = t; } T remove_from_queue() { return queue[start++]; }` You'd prolly want to clean up some rough edges there (like maybe check if start == end, it is empty), but that code would actually work pretty well for a lot of things, is really simple, and has no memory reallocations at all.